# Airflow PythonOperator task does not fail no matter what

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I'm trying to run my python project using airflow 2.0.1 in docker.

So here is catalog structure:

dags are here: path_to_airflow/dags/
python project code is here: path_to_airflow/dags/utils

I faced strange airflow attitude dealing with exceptions: my PythonOperator task is always finishing with success mark and exit code 0 status no matter is there any exception or not.
Can somebody help my with solving this issue?

Here is dag code:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from utils.main import main

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'test',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0),
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False,
)

task_dummy = DummyOperator(
    task_id='task_dummy',
    dag=dag,
)

task_1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task_1',
    python_callable=main,
    dag=dag,
)

task_dummy >> task_1
```

Here is main function code:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException

def main(data_path='/opt/airflow/dags/data/'):

    ...
    some code
    ...
    
    if condition:
        raise AirflowException('empty data')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is dag's log:
[image]

Here is dag's final status:
[image]

All exceptions cat be catched replacing PythonOperator with BashOperator, but I just want to understand what is wrong.
For testing you can just leave exception without condition in a main function.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your second screenshot is from another dag and task.

Comment: I've changed names of original code just to make is simpler, sorry.

Comment: @JarekPotiuk I've edited screenshot.

Comment: How do I know you looked at the right dag/task? I think you might simply had mistake and looked at wrong task/dag status

Comment: I just assesed what you wrote vs the screenshot., You wrote in your text that you see error thrown but the task /dag succeeded. From your screenshot I see that yeah. you had exception, but ANOTHER task and ANOTHER dag succeeded.  So I am asking - very nicely and politely so that you double-check if you actually did not make mistake and the ACTUAL task that threw the exception. This happens that by mistake you look at different output (and this is what your screenshots indicated). So I am just asking if you double checked that you have not made this mistake. no more, no less.

Comment: You can just run it again, and post the right  screnshots that will match the task/dag  if this is still the case - that will give you the opportunity to check again if you made the mistake or not.

Comment: (And I am asking that also because I am 100% sure that raising exception from callable should make the task fail so I am askingh you that also because I think you should double-check)

Comment: Yes, I agree with. So, I was sure too. Anyway I've recreated dag with another name from the scratch and everyting worked like should be. Sorry for disturbing. May be I overworked a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comment, the issue was wrong observation.